# Is it obligatory for a non-Muslim woman to pay jizya?

Tags: fiqh, sharia, women, jihad, jizya

Scholars say that jizya is not obligatory for non Muslim women. Is their any sahih evidence for this.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. You say "scholars" please name some show us and share your research efforts.

Answer (score 2):

No<sup>*</sup>. Jizyah is only due from adult, sane, free, males from the disbelievers.

The basic evidence for this is the verse:

> #### قاتلوا ... حتى يعطوا الجزية
>
> Fight ... until they give the jizyah
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:29](https://quran.com/9/29?translations=20)</sup>

Jizyah is an escape from fighting and execution, while it is forbidden to fight or kill women in the first place, so they don't require the protection of Jizya.

> #### فنهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن قتل النساء والصبيان
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade the killing of women and children.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/224) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/29)</sup>

The hadith on Jizyah has the wording حالم which means adult male:

> #### يأخذ من كل حالم - يعني محتلما - دينارا
>
> When the Prophet (ﷺ) sent Mu'adh ibn Jabal to the Yemen, he ordered him to take  one dinar for every adult (male)
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3038)</sup>

Further there is the instruction of the caliph Umar ibn al-Khatab:

> أن عمر، كتب إلى عماله: لا تضربوا الجزية على النساء والصبيان
>
> Umar wrote to his governors: Do not impose Jizya on the women and the children
>
> <sup>— [Sunan al-Kubra Bayhaqi](https://ia800809.us.archive.org/8/items/FP78881/skb09.pdf#page=333),  [Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah](https://shamela.ws/book/9944/37036) etc.</sup> 
>  <sup>classed as Sahih by al-Albani in  [Irwa' al-Ghaleel](https://shamela.ws/book/22592/1590#p12)</sup>

---

* <sub>This is the view of the overwhelming majority, such that many scholars have claimed consensus on it. However Ibn Hazm has diverged on it.</sub>